# How do I find out which number an SMS is from, out of all the numbers associated with the sender?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-2, sms

In the messaging application it says who is the sender of each message, but it doesn't say the phone number the message was from. From each thread I can get to the corresponding contact, but some contacts have several numbers and I don't know how to tell which number the message was from.

I can get the message details, but again only the name of the contact is listed, and not the number.

I am running ICS on a Galaxy S2 device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my LG optimus one running gingerbread, I can open a message thread and long press on an message. This pops up a list of options and if I press 'view message details' I get details like from, date, time. The value displayed for from is not the contact name rather it is their number.

Alternatively, instead of long press, short press on the sender's name in the message gives an option to call and when I do so and quickly disconnect, I can see the number which is called, which is the number the message came from.

Comment: On my device the message details displays the sender name, and not the number. However, your trick with calling and quickly disconnecting solves the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't hesitate to use a third-party messaging app, then simply install [Go SMS Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms&hl=en), it shows the exact sender's number below her/his name on top of the thread. I'm not aware of any other messaging app that also does this, but this one has many nice features along with that one.